# How to simplify nested looping of XML files using xpath in c# to the simplest form

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have code structure for nested loops but I am curious if it can be simplified into fewer lines of code.

```
 HttpRequestMessage someRequest = GetHttpRequestMessage(new Uri(baseUri, someUrl));
                                        log.Debug(String.Format("Calling URL: {0}", someUrl));
                                        httpResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(someRequest).Result;
                                        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                        string someXml = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                                        XmlDocument someXDoc = new XmlDocument();
                                        someXDoc.LoadXml(someXml);

                                        XPathNavigator someXNav;
                                        someXNav = someXDoc.CreateNavigator();

                                        XPathNodeIterator niSome;
                                        niSome = someXNav.Select("//something");

                                        //Parallel.ForEach(niSome.OfType<XPathNavigator>(), someXNav =>
                                        foreach (XPathNavigator someXNav in niSome)
                                        {
                                         ...some code here and the above repeated
                                         }
```

Comment: I believe there is a stackexchange community for code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

However, in httpClient.SendAsync(), you aren’t awaiting the response, so it will almost certainly throw an error as it hasn’t finished

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b OP is calling `.Result` (which he shouldn't), so it is not going to fail because of that but _may_ for different reasons. adam: [Go async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: @Fildor Either way, that is an issue with this code. I don’t know about how errors are thrown from tasks, but at the very least it should be null.

Comment: Outside the async issues: Depends on what you are doing, specifically. It _may_ be easier to have a model deserialized from the XML and work with that. It _may_ be worthwhile to come up with an XSLT that transforms the data into a simpler and filtered form ... but there's not enough info to make a sophisticated suggestion regarding that.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I think we agree he _should_ be `await`ing the call :D

Comment: @Fildor Or, if not in an async context, .Wait() or .Wait(milliseconds).